# C# - How to shift focus from one text box to another?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
 private void a1_1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
       {
        if (a1_1.Text.Length == 1)
            a1_2.Focus();
       }
```

This worked well in in Windows 8.0 app.

In Windows 8.1 I am getting an error that "No overload method of Focus takes 0 arguments.

Kindly help

thank you in advance

I am sorry as the question was basic and since I am new to windows  8 programming I didnt knew it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass a value in your Focus method. The method takes [FoucsState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702161.aspx) as argument

```
a1_2.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic)
```

or any other value from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.focusstate.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I tried that before. But I get the error message . "The best overloaded method match for "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState) has some invalid arguments